# What's the point of Matlab's "complex" function?

Tags: matlab

`c=complex(a,b)` in matlab is much slower than doing `c=a+1i*b`.

The following is in Matlab 2018a

```
a=rand(15000);
b=rand(15000);

%
clear c; 
tic; c=a+1i*b; toc
Elapsed time is 0.338525 seconds

%
clear c; 
tic; c=complex(a,b); toc
Elapsed time is 2.542403 seconds.
```

Is the `complex` actually useful in any situation? Why is it so slow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/complex.html) and the command-line help give some hints as to **when it may be useful**: when you want to force a complex-type result even if the imaginary part is zero, or when you have integer data types as inputs:

> `C = COMPLEX(A,B)` returns the complex result `A + Bi`
>
> In the event that `B` is all zeros, `C` is complex with all zero imaginary part, unlike the result of the addition `A+0i`, which returns a strictly real result.
>
> The `complex` function provides a useful substitute for expressions such as `A+1i*B` or `A+1j*B` in cases when `A` and `B` are not single or double, or when `B` is all zero.

As for **why it is slower**: we can only guess, because it's a built-in function; but checking if the inputs are not floating point or if the second input is all zeros may account for some of the extra time.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to add some historical perspective:

In versions of MATLAB prior to R2018a, complex numbers were stored in separate real and imaginary arrays internally. Thus, the result of `complex` could just point at the data for the two input arrays. `complex(a,b)` was thus very fast and memory-efficient compared to `a+1i*b` which actually needs to do arithmetic and create new memory storage.

In the current version of MATLAB, complex data is stored in “interleaved format”, meaning it’s a single array with real and complex values for each array element next to each other. This means data needs to be copied with either format, `complex` has lost its value.

Comment: That is exactly the functionality I am looking for and was surprised complex does not do. However, I tried it on 2016b back when they used the separate and real arrays for real and imaginary parts and complex is still very slow compared to a+1i*b.

Comment: This is discussed more in the [release notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#mw_0052762c-8e9f-482a-9749-30979ecd435c), and  [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-support-for-interleaved-complex.html) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/390105-r2018a-complex-interleaved-data-is-the-new-memory-model).

Answer (score 2):

***Why is it so slow?***

It isn't, really. But your "benchmark code" is not appropriate, as it does may behave differently for every run or by changing the order.

The [**`timeit`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) function is the dedicated function for benchmarks.

```
function [t] = bench()
    A = rand(10000);
    B = rand(10000);

    % functions to compare
    fcns = {
        @() compare1(A,B);
        @() compare2(A,B);
    };

    % timeit
    t = zeros(2,1);
    for ii = 1:10
        t = t + cellfun(@timeit, fcns);
    end
end

function c = compare1(a,b)  
    c = a + 1i*b;
end
function c = compare2(a,b) 
    c = complex(a,b);
end
```

for ten runs it leads to:

```
8.0663 % a + 1i*b
8.3191 % complex(a,b)
```

As you see, there is not much of a difference. The one there is, can be accounted for the function overhead of `complex` (type-check, cast) as mentioned by Luis Mendo.

---

Some more reasons in addition to [Luis Mendo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51813846/2605073), why this function may exist:

- historical reasons, backwards compatibility
- Nowadays you can just do `[1,2,3]+1i*[1;2;3]` which is the same as `bsxfun(@(x,y) x+1i*y, [1,2,3], [1;2;3])`, but this `bsxfun(@complex, [1,2,3], [1;2;3])` is presumably faster than the second option (same applies for cellfun and arrayfun, though I can't test it.)
- **Maybe most importantly: Code generation.** Matlab can automatically generate C-code from Matlab code, where `complex` is supported and `a+1i*b` isn't. There are various industrial applications, which heavily rely on this feature.

Comment: I should have timed it several times and taken an average, but on my machine a+1i*b is still faster. I believe you might be using a very slow processor or only 1 core? Here's my results using your code with 16 and 1 threads, respectively: 
   
    1.0453, 
    6.1013
and 
  11.9702,
    5.8633

Comment: @avgn That is indeed quite a difference. So it seems to be highly multi-core optimized. I tested it with 4 threads.

Comment: @avgn, does your numbers mean, that for one core, `complex` is faster?

Comment: complex does not scale with cores significantly. While I expect a+b*1i would with the number and frequency of the cores - so it depends on the set up.